# How to run sudo command as root?

Tags: debian, root, sudo, chmod

I only have root access to my server and the sudo command therefore does not work.  I am trying to run a command that tries to use the sudo command and as I already have root access, it fails.

> command not found: sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way that I can get this command to run?  Can I move out of root somehow, or make root temporarily able to use the sudo command?

Comment: if you are already logged as root you do not need to call sudo

Comment: I do, in order to run a script that uses the "sudo" command and gives the error above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried it and it worked for me
(on Mandriva Linux; other distros shouldn't be different).

Do you really have `sudo` installed?
It is not by default on some distros.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need sudo if you already are root. Just remove the word sudo.

sudo is a tool to get root access as a normal user.

Comment: I am unable to remove the word sudo as it is embedded in the script somewhere

Comment: Then you can install the sudo program, how you do that is depending on what distriution you have, on ubuntu or debian you would do it like this:

apt-get install sudo

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as root can't you just run your command without the sudo?

ie

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: It is part of a script i.e. pdfkit --install-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you normally don't need to use sudo if you are already root. But if you write some scripts or something like that and need to run it when you use root and not root users you need to put the full part to your sudo command.
You can locate where sudo app is situated running `whereis sudo` from a non-root user. Normally sudo situated at:

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

So you can write in your script:
/usr/bin/sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: Thanks for your understanding and for your tip

Answer (score 0):

"Can I move out of root somehow?"

You could make another user account, and log into that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you simply don't have sudo installed:

> command not found: sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Just install it! sudo should be configured by default to allow being called by root without even asking
for password...